# Problema al obtener el valor de todas las filas de un datatable jquery

Tags: html, jquery, datatables

Tengo el siguiente fragmento de código que lo que hace es obtener el valor de la columna 0 de todas las filas seleccionadas del datatable y mostrarlos en un alert:

```
var dataArr = [];
$.each($("#tablaDatos tr.selected"),function(){ //get each tr which has selected class
dataArr.push($(this).find('td').eq(0).text()); //find its first td and push the value
});
alert(dataArr);
```

Hasta aquí todo correcto. El problema viene cuando hago un botón para seleccionar todos los registros del datatable (incluidos los ocultos en otras páginas ya que tiene paginación), que en este caso, si intento obtener los valores de las filas seleccionadas, solo me muestra los valores de las filas seleccionadas de la página actual, es decir, las filas que se ven, ya que las filas que están en otras páginas y están seleccionadas no me muestra su valor.

He probado a recorrer el tbody de cada thead del datatable pero claro, solo hay un thead y me hace lo mismo.

**CÓDIGO HTML:**

```
<body class="dt-tablaDatos dt-tablaDatos-bootstrap">
<div class="container" id="contenedorHeight">
    <div class="row">
    <section>
        <input type="hidden" id="filasSeleccionadas" value="" />
        <table id="tablaDatos" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th data-priority="1">Id.Pieza</th>
                    <th>*</th>
                    <th>Num.Serie</th>
                    <th>Cod. Art.</th>
                    <th>Descripcion</th>
                    <th data-priority="2">Acción</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>

                </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hay que obtener los renglones a traves de fnGetNodes():

```
oTable = $('#tablaDatos').dataTable( {
...
});

var rows = oTable.fnGetNodes();

for(rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < rows.length; rowIndex++) {
    dataArr.push( $(rows[rowIndex]).find('td:eq(0)') );
}
```